# Which plugin of maven is better for manage release version?

Tags: java, maven, release

For example:
`maven-release-plugin`  `prepare perform`  requires not having SNAPSHOT dependencies, this breaks the continuous integration in case of not being validated before the release, instead, `flatten-maven-plugin` only require `-Drevision -Dchangelist scm:tag` for tag the release version and not validate SNAPSHOT dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Having SNAPSHOT dependencies in a release version is always a bad idea. The build becomes non-reproducible.

The Maven Release Plugin offers you a thorough and thought-through release process. There are different opinions about some aspects of it, and if you don't like them, you can construct your own way, possibly in your build server (Jenkins) instead of Maven.

Comment: ... I cannot have control of the new dependencies added (multiple developers), that incurs that the release is broken and I have to reverse the changes made by `prepare perform` of maven.

Comment: You could call `versions:use-releases -DfailIfNotReplaced=true` before calling the maven release plugin. Then the build will fail almost immediately if SNAPSHOT dependencies are present and cannot be replaced.

Comment: Yes, is correct. For CI isn't friendly because this proces is manual. `prepare perform` is ugly for CI.

Comment: Whether CI or not: You need to make sure that releases are not build with Snapshot dependencies. So you need one way or another to fail the build if Snapshot dependencies are in it.